# pip install with target directory but skip already installed system packages

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-packaging, python-venv

The `pip install --target` lets you install Python packages into a specific directory which can then be added to the PYTHONPATH (basically creating something similar to a virtualenv but without the Python interpreter and libs).

However, I have a use-case where I'd like to install packages into the target directory, but skip the install of a transitive dependency if a compatible version is already satisfied on the PYTHONPATH.

For example, since the `requests` package depends on `urllib3` and if a requests-compatible version of `urllib3` is already installed on the PYTHONPATH of my current Python interpreter / pip executable, I'm hoping to have way to install `requests` to the "target" directory, but skip the install of `urllib3` (since it is already present).

I understand that it makes sense for the default behavior of `pip install --target` to install full copies to the target directory, but am wondering if there's something similar to virtualenv's `--system-site-packages` flag to include system site packages when evaluating what to install in the target dir.

How can I pip install to a target directory but not install copies of packages installed at the system level? Thanks for reading; any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, this statement "_basically creating something similar to a virtualenv but without the Python interpreter and libs_" is misguided. Virtual environments do not contain (or duplicate) the Python interpreter and the standard library. So what you are doing seems like it would be perfectly solved by a virtual environment (with access to system packages). -- Is there another reason why you do not want to use a virtual environment?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The  reason I'm not using a full-blown virtualenv for this is that I'm already running this in custom-crafted docker container with a specific python version and python dependencies.  The target directory is a swappable path of _additional_ python packages that would be added to the python path at runtime. So I already have a fairly isolated python bin that I want to use and just add packages to it, and avoid re-installing packages that are already available in the container. (For context, I'm using this in k8s; different pods would get different target dirs added)

Comment: I still do not understand how what you wrote implies that using virtual environment is not possible, but whatever, I believe you. -- How about taking things the other way around and transform this *target* directory into a virtual environment? It should not be too hard in principle, and it is well documented. -- Other idea is to create a virtual environment and add inside that environment a `.pth` file that points to the directory where the other dependencies are already installed. It should be even easier.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. So it sounds like the `--target` syntax doesn't support this use-case. To your point about virtualenvs, perhaps I could install the packages in a venv. Then I could copy out the site-packages and bin directories from the venv into some other dir; this seems to be basically what `--target` it doing effectively. That way, I could use the system site packages for the install, but have the `--target` dir structure that my project has standardized on. (I really don't need the python interprater in the virtualenv for this use-case)

Comment: Again: there is no Python interpreter in the virtual environment. The `python` binary that one can find in the virtual environment's directory is not a full Python interpreter, it is just a *shim* (or whatever it is called, sometimes I think it is even just a *symlink*) pointing to the actual Python interpreter that was used to create the virtual environment.